# Typing Returned Anonymous Class in a TypeScript Function

Tags: typescript

I have a use case to dynamically return a class:

```
export default function model<D extends ...> (): ??? {
  return class Model {
    static async get (): Promise<D> { ... }
  }
}
```

Then how do I type the return type of the function `model`?
Cuz the type of the returned `class Model` is described in the implementation of the function itself.
Thanks.

Comment: What `D` should extend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit the return type. TypeScript will infer the return type from you implementation, for example:

```
export default function model<D>() {
  return class Model {
    static async get(): Promise<D> {
      return undefined as unknown as D;
    }
  }
}
```

Editor hover on `model` shows:

```
function model<D>(): typeof Model
```

And emitted `.d.ts` is like

```
export default function model<D>(): {
    new (): {};
    get(): Promise<D>;
};
```

---

If you really want to manually type the return value (for example you have the eslint rule for explicit return type), the `.d.ts` above already told you the answer, where `new (): T` means it's a constructor ([TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures))

Comment: Yes, I have to pass the linter rules. Finally I copy-and-paste the generated type in `.d.ts` to solve the problem, though not that pretty : )